# Django import-export: Change language

Tags: django, django-admin

For the third party extension [django-import-export](https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export/), I just want to change the language of the buttons "import" and "export" of the Admin when I'm using this application(Django import/export).

Any ideas how I would accomplish this?

Comment: Well as far as I know there are no "import" and "export" buttons in the admin by default. Secondly, I am curious why you would only want to translate that button and nothing else.

Comment: @dan-klasson I'm not talking about the Admin interface by default but the addon that the app "Django import-export" provides. I don't want to translate the rest since Django allows it through settings.py. https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for django import-export? If they don't provide a translation in their source, then you'll need to add it in the appropriate location, which is most likely their admin templates.

Comment: Just look at the source code. I guess you just have to overwrite those gettext variables: https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/templates/admin/import_export/change_list_import_export.html

Comment: You can thank me by accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to translate these [gettext variables](https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/templates/admin/import_export/change_list_import_export.html):

```
 <li><a href="import/" class="import_link">{% trans "Import" %}</a></li>
 <li><a href="export/{{ cl.get_query_string }}" class="export_link">{% trans "Export" %}</a></li>
```